# Can I correct double exposure of 35mm film?

Tags: film, double-exposure

I have a set of developed colour photos taken using 35 mm film which are double exposed. I must have taken a 2nd set of photos using the used film. Can they be corrected?

Comment: long story short.... switch to DSLR.

Comment: ... or go and check out https://www.flickr.com/photos/hodachrome/ to see the creative potential of film double exposures when done properly ;-)

Comment: Sometimes this can result in an  Interesting photo.  "happy accident" ! Keep them for your grand kids.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can not correct double exposure.

Film exposure is one way street - you can not reverse  the process, just like you can not reverse the changes in the silver ion that has been struck by light (or turn omelette back into eggs).

Comment: Didn't think so, but worth a try in asking as my photos were from a honeymoon trip! Got a different camera now,